# jquery toggle open all div s on one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

Please take a look at below codes, for whatever reason I am unable to open one div only when I click on the edit link, it opens all divs when I click the edit link.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:button[name='uploadboy']").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('.uploadboy').slideToggle(200, 'swing');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="overflow:auto;" class="links-box ">
    <p style="float:left; width:250px;" id="links">
        <input type="button" name="uploadboy" id="uploadboy" value="Uploaded" title="Uploaded" style="text-decoration:none;  color: white; text-shadow:none; background: #0692fe; float:left;" class="g-button">
    </p>
</div>
<div class="uploadboy" width: 600px;min-height:50px;background-color: #F2FDD7;border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid #8EBD43;">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
<div style="overflow:auto;" class="links-box ">
    <p style="float:left; width:250px;" id="links">
        <input type="button" name="uploadboy" id="uploadboy" value="Uploaded" title="Uploaded" style="text-decoration:none;  color: white; text-shadow:none; background: #0692fe; float:left;" class="g-button">
    </p>
</div>
<div class="uploadboy" width: 600px;min-height:50px;background-color: #F2FDD7;border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid #8EBD43;">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

[example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMkZn/)

Comment: Note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: You have two element which have same ID `uploadboy` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below script, **.find** method only searches for the descendants (http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:button[name='uploadboy']").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().next('.uploadboy').slideToggle(200, 'swing');
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're clicking on the button, why should you have to go up and then down the DOM to get back to that same button?

Comment: Please update the HTML, it doesn't contain any element with uploadboy class -  @user3147472

Comment: You don't have an uploadboy class...you only have 2 classes in your example: links-box and g-button. You don't have the class "uploadboy"

Comment: sorry after the links-box class should appear uploadboy class

Comment: I have updated the answer, please try this @user3147472

Comment: **I have updated the code** - *Please update the question with proper HTML, wrong HTML is causing a lot of confusion*

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, IDs must be unique. That said, try this:

```
$("input").click(function () {
    $(this).slideToggle(200, 'swing');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kfhBZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

What I initially see here that's an issue is that you have 2 input buttons with the same id. While this may not be the overall issue, you still can't have 2 elements with the same id. I also am not sure if this is just generic code you cleaned to ask a question, but your selectors seem pretty complicated. You attach the .click event to both input buttons, then you go to the buttons parent, which is the paragraph, then you go the child object which is the button. You are essentially going from point one spot, up a level, then back down a level. When the click handler is attached to the button, anytime you click a button, you can reference $(this) to refer to the button.

```
<input type="button" name="uploadboy" id="button1" />
<input type="button" name="uploadboy" id="button2" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:button[name='uploadboy']").click(function () {
        $(this).SlideToggle(200, 'swing');
    });
});
```

If you look at the function that is ran when the input button is clicked, it simply refers to the $(this) object. This is a benefit of jquery and $(this) is the specific button that you clicked. Even if there are 20 buttons on the page, whatever button is clicked will be this. So in the above example, the button clicked will have the slide toggle occur. You could also navigate the dom off of this if you need to move around like before.

Comment: Well you are going to have to create unique Ids. You cannot have 2 elements on the same page with the same ID. That's not a "you shouldn't do that" it's actually "That's wrong and you can't do that"